# PHP - session variable cannot be set

Tags: php

I wrote a page 'captcha.php' to generate a math captcha and send the result through session to the page which request it.
In captcha.php:

```
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $var;//$var is the calculate result
```

In index.php:

```
<img src="/captcha.php"/><input id="captchaa" type="text" name="a"/>
...
<?php    
if($_POST['a']==$_SESSION['captcha'])
...
```

But I got 'Undefined index: captcha' error.
Any hint? Or what else more information do you need?

UPDATE:
these lines are in both files

    if(!isset($_SESSION))
    {
        session_start();
    }

UPDATE:
I think i found the reason. My index.php is in the frame of Yii, and it has a session with id, but the captcha.php is not within the framework, so they cannot share a session.I tried to make it a view(/validation/captcha ),but it won't generate image properly that way, don't know why.
 Now the problem is how to use Yii's session in captcha.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you use the [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) function in both your files?

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you set the session var in captcha.php and you use that file to render that image also, considering that the image is shown before you check the answer received, the value saved in your session will be changed at the time of your check

Comment: if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_start();
}is in both of the two files.

Comment: I think i found the reason. My index.php is in the frame of Yii, and it has a session with id, but the captcha.php is not within the framework, so they cannot share a session.I tried to make it a view(/validation/captcha ),but it won't generate image properly that way, don't know why.

Now the problem is how to use Yii's session in captcha.php.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `captcha.php` is processed in a separate request by **browser**. So, the flow is the following:

1. PHP executes `index.php` file. **NO** `$_SESSION['captcha']` is set, so nothing is outputted
2. PHP flushes the content to the browser.
3. Browser sees `src` parameter of the `img` and loades that url
4. PHP executes `captcha.php` and sets `$_SESSION['captcha']`, but the page is already rendered.

So, actually your `$_SESSION['captcha']` is set **after** the `index.php` is processed and even after another `HTTP` request.

As a workaround you may use AJAX loading captcha, passing both captcha value and image via AJAX request and than injecting them into HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the rest of captcha.php, have you called session_start() before setting the session variable?

Answer (score 0):

The variable $_SESSION['captcha'] will not be available in index.php until the next page load as it is being created in a request after the one you are currently in, if that make sense.

Checking if the form has been submitted /then/ checking the value against the $_SESSION should work as long as session_start() is being used correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **mishu** about session_start. 'Undefined index: captcha' is not an error. It's rather a warning. If you don't suppress the output of warning messages, you should check if specified array index really exists:

```
if(isset($_POST['a']) && isset($_SESSION['captcha'])&&$_POST['a']==$_SESSION['captcha'])
...
```

to suppress warnings output you should use [error_reportning](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) function, if it's not critical to you.

Comment: I did as you've said and the procedure was also post then check, but var_dump($_SESSION['captcha']) is always NULL